# Problema con Paragraph de Itext y CK Editor de Primefaces

Tags: java, html, primefaces, itext, ckeditor

Tengo un problema al leer en java una cadena HTML generada con CK Editor de Primefaces:

Al momento de aplicar estilos de negrita, cursiva o subrayado al texto y cambiando el tamaño de la fuente, el html generado queda de la siguiente forma:

[image: HTML generado con CK Editor]

En un visor de HTML saldría correctamente el texto con los estilos aplicados y 
tamaño 14, sin embargo al momento de leerlo en Java para un reporte PDF utilizando itext, ignora la propiedad style, no puede leerla debido a que no
está dentro del tag strong.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna librería o método para formatear el HTML para que ordene de forma correcta los atributos y tags, o si puedo parsear el HTML
de alguna otra manera que acepte este tipo de ordenamiento, actualmente
estoy utilizando Parser, itext, HtmlPipelineContext y HtmlPipeline

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola AMiranda, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Es preferible que tu código lo pongas en la pregunta en forma de texto y no en una imagen, y de preferencia en forma de un [mcve]